# MSBuild. Create EmbeddedResource before build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I want to embed local references in the assembly before compiling the main unit. But the written target does not work.

```
  <Target Name="EmbedLocal" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <Message Text="Run EmbedLocal for $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)..." Importance="high"/>    
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@( ReferencePath->WithMetadataValue( 'CopyLocal', 'true' )->Metadata( 'FullPath' ) )"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Embed local references complete for $(OutputPath)$(TargetFileName)." Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

@(EmbeddedResource) at this moment contains valid list of paths.

**Update:**
 
Now my import file contains:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="$(MSBuildToolsVersion)" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EmbedLocalReferences Condition=" '$(EmbedLocalReferences)' == '' ">True</EmbedLocalReferences>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="EmbedLocal" BeforeTargets="ResolveReferences" Condition=" '$(EmbedLocalReferences)' == 'True' ">
    <Message Text="Run EmbedLocal for $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)..." Importance="high"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue( 'Extension', '.dll' )->Metadata( 'FullPath' ))">
        <LogicalName>%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>   
    <Message Text="Embed local references complete for $(OutputPath)$(TargetFileName)." Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

It works fine. Output assembly contains all .dll references as EmbeddedResource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> MSBuild. Create EmbeddedResource before build

You can try to use **BeforeBuild** action to the csproj file to include the embedded resources:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    ... 
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="..."/>
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
  </Target>
```

Now MSBuild will add this file as embedded resource into your assembly.

**Update:**

Thanks @Martin Ullrich. He pointed out the correct direction, we could use `<Target Name="EmbedLocal" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">` in the `Directory.Build.props` to resolve this issue. You can check if it works for you.

```
  <Target Name="EmbedLocal" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    ... 
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="..."/>
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
  </Target>
```

Comment: I have several projects where I want to include this logic. I would not want to copy-paste it when it changes. And the use of "BeforeBuild" depends on the place of inserting the import into the main project (only after importing CSharpTargets).

Comment: @R.Savelyev, Got it. If you do not want to modify the project one by one, we could use [Directory.Build.props or Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build), but the `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">` could not triggered by MSBuild, we have to use like `<Target Name="EmbedLocal" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">`. But you will got the original issue, could not embedded resource into your assembly.

Comment: Does it change if you also set the `<Link>` metadata? It is automatically added in the `PrepareForBulid` target for exiting `EmbeddedResource` items. Marking the target as `BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"` may help here. (btw naming a target `BeforeBuild` is discouraged now, use `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"` / `AfterTargets="AfterBuild"` as the new project system does in 15.3+)

Comment: @R.Savelyev, Martin Ullrich pointed the correct direction, and I have test it, it works fine, you can check if it works for you, see the updated answer for more details.

Comment: @MartinUllrich, you are right. I have test it with BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild", it works fine. I do not know `BeforeBuild` is discouraged until you told me, is there any documentation or blog here to explain the reason this, I want to learn much about it, would you please provide some link about it for me? Thank you very much :).

Comment: TL;DR for SDK style project the targets are defined before M.Common.targets, which will use them for build events (that's why they are commented out below common targets in classic csproj templates). build events suffer from a similar issue: most properties are defined in the common targets and thus unavailable in main body for SDK-style projects

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/2367 now uses targets for build events edited through project properties