# Copy files for use as embedded resources

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, csproj

I have a .NET Core project, and before building I'd like to copy files from outside of the project folder, so they can be uses as embedded resources.

My csproj file looks like this:

```xml
<Target Name="CopyResources" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\..\config\00.sql" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)\Resources\Sql" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\..\config\01.sql" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)\Resources\Sql" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\..\config\02.sql" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)\Resources\Sql" />
</Target>

<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Sql\*.sql" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, there seems to be a race condition - the files are copied to the destination folder as expected, but are not getting included as embedded resources on the first build. They are being included on subsequent builds - it appears that the build target is being executed asynchronously, and not completing before the build starts.

I tried changing `BeforeTargets` to `Compile` instead of `PreBuildEvent`, but get the same behaviour.

I also tried using an `Exec` task, but got the same result:

```xml
<Exec Command="copy $(ProjectDir)..\..\config\*.sql $(ProjectDir)\Resources\Sql" />
```

Is there some way to ensure a `BeforeTargets` build target *actually* executes before the specified target?

**Update**
So I thought to add a sleep in the `Exec` task, and I can see that it at least *appears* to wait before proceeding to the build stage:

```xml
<Exec Command="copy $(ProjectDir)..\..\config\*.sql $(ProjectDir)\Resources\Sql && sleep 5" />
```

However, the copied files still don't get added as embedded resources the first time the copy happens. I wonder if this is a specific issue with embedded resources?

Comment: If you really want to use `Copy`, make sure to create `FileWrites` items from Copy's `CopiedFiles` output parameter so the files are cleaned up during incremental builds and you don't end up with files in your project directory that you deleted from the `config\` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best to include them from outside the project folder using `LinkBase`. No target and copy steps needed.:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\config\*.sql" LinkBase="Resources\Sql\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you don't want to see them in the solution explorer, you can add `Visible="False"` to the `EmbeddedResource` xml tag.

Comment: If I do that, will the names of the embedded resources still be as expected, e.g. `MyAssembly.Resources.Sql.myfile.sql`?

Comment: Yes the logical name is defaulted to the link metadata (inferred from `LinkBase` + (recursive dir if `**/` wildcard) + filename + extension in .NET Sdk projects). It could also be customised through the `LogicalName` metadata if one wants different location on disk, in solution explorer and name/path in the generated assembly)

Comment: Excellent, this does indeed work as expected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, courtesy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609999/25758) answer:

```xml
  <Target Name="EmbedLocal" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="... " DestinationFolder="... " />
    ... 
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="..."/>
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
  </Target>
```

Having the `EmbeddedResource` tasks inside the same custom target as the `Copy` tasks seems to ensure that it doesn't try to embed resources until *after* the files are copied.